# Rails 4 routes passing default parameter without having to include it on url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this routes in my **routes.rb**

```
get "/whats_new/:only_new" => 'products#index', as: :whats_new_page_products, :defaults => { :only_new => true }
```

and its produces:

```
localhost:3000/whats_new/true
```

is there any way to only show it as:

```
localhost:3000/whats_new/
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could just do

```
get ':whats_new' => 'products#index', as: :whats_new_page_products, :defaults => {:whats_new => true }
```

That should produce the results you want.  Just keep in mind in your controller action everytime you had `params[:only_new]` you'll now need to do `params[:whats_new]`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`get "/whats_new(/:only_new)" => 'products#index', as: :whats_new_page_products`

That will create an optional parameter, which you can check for in your controller.

Now users can make requests to `/whats_new` or `/whats_new/true` (replace true with any parameter value). In your controller, you can check to see if params[:only_new] is true or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
get :whats_new, to: "products#index", as: :whats_new_page_products #-> url.com/whats_new

#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      if /^(whats_new)$/ !~ request.path
        @products = Product.only_new
      else
        @products = Product.all
      end
   end
end
```

I don't think you need to pass a param to identify the request. The above is slightly hacky, but should work.